# DataTable DateTime difference between oracle database

Tags: oracle, datetime, datatable

I'm getting date from oracle to datatable, but the date is not correct. But if I get date to simple string, the date is correct.

The real data in the Oracle: 2015-01-01 09:00:00 (real)
In the datatable the same date is: 2015-01-01 16:00:00
If I get this date to simple string, I get this: 2015-01-01 09:00:00 (real)

The Oracle server is in the USA, the IIS Webservice is in Ireland, and the application is running in different countries.

I tried change the column DateTimeMode, but it is not possible if there are data. I did not want to change individually..

But I cant create columns before the query, because I need dynamic columns.

Could you help me please?

Comment: How are you querying to get the various values? What data type is the column - I'm guessing timestamp with time zone, and your client/app is translating it to your local time zone?

Comment: are you exporting data from USA DBMS server to IRELAND DBMS server ?

Comment: What do you query? `CURRENT_DATE`, `LOCALTIMESTAMP`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `SYSDATE` or `SYSTIMESTAMP`

Comment: What do you mean by "real" time? Do you expect any imaginary time?

Comment: I'm using the simple SELECT * FROM .... Okay, I know, it is not the best. But in this case I have to use.

Comment: The type of the column is DATE

Comment: The Oracle send the date correctly, and the IIS send too. I think the problem is in the DataTable.... For example I use this query: SELECT TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') works well...

Comment: I have tried to change the Culture for the entire application, but it didn't work.

Comment: Wernfried: Sorry, my english is not the best. I mean the correct, the inserted date.

Comment: Vikash Singh: I expect data from USA DBMS server trough on the Irish IIS WebService for the applications. I found the problem on the application side. But I dont want to get the date from the DB by string. That is working, but not my way. I want to get the date by date.